# Progress bar and axios in react native

Tags: react-native, axios

This post on axios is responsible for inserting data into mysql...

I believe that onUploadProgress works only with files...

```
await api
  .post('/embryo-transfer/create', obj, {
    onUploadProgress: (event) => {
      let progressValue = Math.round(
        (event.loaded * 100) / event.total
      );

      setTimeout(function() {

        setProgress(progressValue);
      }, 2000)

    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you give more clearity about your question and edit it that way please?